# Derivation of Result from java for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

Complete the following for loop to produce the following output:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {

//your code

}
```

-4

14

32

50

68

86

I know the answer is:

```
int x = -22; 
int y = 18; 
x += y * i; 
System.out.println(x);
```

But how do you derive that answer? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is more maths related but to do this you have to first work out the difference between each term (in a linear sequence) and this gets you x (14 - -4 = 18). To calculate y you have to calculate how much you're off by when you multiply the term number by x (-4 - 18 = -22)

To actually calculate the sequence you have to multiply the term number by x and then add y to it

eg 5th term would be (5 * 18) + (-22) = 68